# Is it more efficient to use the CASE in the original query or in a separate query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, case-when, proc-sql

I can't show the real query, but here is an example of the type of thing I'm doing:

```
select
  t1.contract,
  t1.state,
  t1.status,
  t2.product,
  case
    when t2.product_cost > 100 and t3.status = 'Closed' then 'Success'
    when t2.product_cost <= 100 and t3.status = 'Closed' then 'Semi-Success'
    else 'Failure'
  end as performance,
  t3.sales_date
from contract_table as t1 
left join product_table as t2 on t1.prodkey = t2.prodkey
left join sales_table as t3 on (t1.client_number = t3.client_number and t1.contract=t3.contract)
where t1.client_number in (1, 2, 5, 8, 10)
```

The tables involved have currently have 27 million records in them and are growing fast.

This query will be put in a view and then used to generate various summaries.

My question is this.  Would it be more efficient to join the 3 tables into 1 view that has the detail needed to do the case statements and then run a second query that creates the new variables using the case statements?  Or is it more efficient to do what I'm doing here?

Basically, I'm ignorant as to how SQL processes the select statement and accounts for the where statement filtering on the clients from the contract table but not the sales table even though the client_number field is in both.

Comment: Views are not a way to improve performance (except for materialized views).  So, putting all the logic in a single should have the same or better performance than using a view (most likely the same).

Comment: Sql is awesome at data logic (storing records with unique constraints, retrieving records).  Your case statement however looks like business logic (if greater than this adjust that).  Business logic can change too, and can easily have tests written against it.  That '100' should be a constant for instance.  I would suggest just querying the data and applying the evaluation of the performance in your application.  So, if a user queries for 'Closed', you could then pass in the at-that-moment value of 100.  Put an index on product_cost and anything in a where or join and it will cook.

Comment: That makes sense @BlackjacketMack.  Unfortunately, there isn't an end application that the data will be feeding into.  But building off of that, I wonder if a better approach to this would be to turn the business logic into data logic that builds a temp table on the fly that is then joined to my detail table.  Then my main query doesn't have to be updated for business logic changes.  I realize that's probably another topic, but something I should think about.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I don't think the OP is using the view as a way to improve performance.  His question is more like... since I am using this view, for X reason (probably to bring information together from various tables), which way will give better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All other things being equal, the only thing I can see that would change the efficiency one way or another would be whether you have where clause conditions in your outer query.  If that outer query performed on the view is going to have where clauses that limit the number of records returned, then it would be more efficient to put the case statements on it.  That way the case operation will only be performed on the records that pass those conditions, rather than getting performed on every record that passes the view's conditions, only to have those values thrown away by the outer query.

With views, I tend to keep to pretty raw data, as much as possible.  Partly, for this reason, so that any query operating on the view, after deciding what rows to use, can do the necessary operations only on those rows.

As for how sql accounts for filtering on the clients from the contract table but not the sales table, think through both the where clause and the joins.  The where clause says grab only the records where the contract table's client is 1,2,5,8,10.  But the join conditions tell it to only grab the records from sales where that table's client number matches the contract table's client number.  If the only records it's grabbing from contract are 1,2,5,8,10, then the only records from sale that will match that join will be the ones where the client numbers are also 1,2,5,8,10.  Does that make sense?

Comment: In the example here, since both t1 and t3 have a client_number, would it be better to add the filter "t3.client_number in" to my where statement in addition to the t1.client_number filter, or is SQL smart enough to figure that out itself?

Comment: No, you are already filtering on t1.client_number in your where condition, and the join (left join sales table t3 on t3.client_number = t1.client_number) already extends that filter to the sales table.  See the explanation I added to my answer.

Comment: @Agapwlesu, thanks, that does make sense...and now that I think about it, duh, I should have realized that.

Comment: No worries.  I was just reading a book that talks about how that phenomenon happens to everybody.  Once we have learned something or had something pointed out to us, it can seem so obvious that we wonder how we didn't see it ourselves.